Including a Latex file in the middle of another Latex file
I have a Latex file containing its own style, figures, bibliography etc. I have a second file, with a different style, more figures, more references etc. I need to include the first file as part of the second one, such that this first file doesn't break the flow of the second one. Basically, I want the figures and references in this first file to be self contained within the larger, second file. So, for example, if the last figure is file 2, before adding file 1, was Fig. 7, I want the figures in the file 1, within file 2, to start from Fig. 1, not Fig. 8. Then, the first Figure after file 1, in file 2, should continue with Fig. 8. Same for references. How can I do this? For reference, I am writing my thesis, and I want to include at the beginning of each chapter the published papers resulted from that work, as self contained entities. Thank you!

You could use pdfpages to include the pdf of the second file.

Have a look a this: https://overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects

Is file 1 a (La)TeX file, or a compiled PDF?
